# Updating the size of a vector of pointers using push_back inside a function class

Tags: c++, class, vector, push-back

I´m having a problem using push_back of a vector of a class inside a function class.

My codes are [All variables are in Portuguese, sorry]:

My Main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    //blah blah before here...

    vector <C_Aerogerador*> ptrAerogeradores;

    //the following lines are just for example
    int size = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptrAerogeradores.push_back(new C_Aerogerador);
    }

    //OK, now I have a vector of pointer with size 4

    //Creating an object of C_Aerogerador to call a function Class of C_Aerogerador 
    C_Aerogerador * teste = new C_Aerogerador;

    teste->carregaConfig(ptrAerogeradores);

    //PROBLEM! After the calling of the function carregaConfig the 
    // size of ptrAerogeradores is still 4

}
```

And the function carregaConfig of the C_Aerogerador´Class is:

```
void C_Aerogerador::carregaConfig(vector <C_Aerogerador*> ptrAerogerador)
{

    //blah blah, setting some values in ptrAerogerador
    // example:
    ptrAerogerador[0]->areaVarrida = 5;

    //after adding some values I want to push back the ptrAerogerador
    ptrAerogerador.push_back(new C_Aerogerador);
    // It didn't work.
}
```

Comment: Your function has a local copy of the input parameter vector. Look up "pass by reference".

Comment: If you really need pointers, use smart pointers or a `boost::ptr_<cont>` container.

Comment: @RodolfoCalderonMachado (below comment), The elements are copied. The copied elements point to the same place.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I understand what you mean, but the the line  ptrAerogerador[0]->areaVarrida = 5; is adding a value correctly, I checked using debug in Main, so, why push_back are not working?

Comment: Because of what I already said.

Comment: Got it! Tks @juanchopanza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function signature to take a reference of this `vector`

```
void C_Aerogerador::carregaConfig(vector <C_Aerogerador*>& ptrAerogerador);
                                                      // ^ Note
```

Otherwise you're just changing a copy of your original `vector` on the functions parameter stack.

Comment: @RodolfoCalderonMachado De nada! Glad to help ;)